# How to pass json data input to jquery circliful plug-in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use jquery circliful plug-in to create a set of circlular statistics from json data, but it's not working as expected, wanted to display the "**value**" key from json and embed that data values into circular statistics graph.

```
  {
"employee":[
  {
    "name": "test123",
    "value": "20"
  },
   {
    "name": "test456",
    "value": "30"
  },
   {
    "name": "test789",
    "value": "40"
  }
]
```

}

HTML snippet:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div id="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $("#circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: 80 // mapping values for circular statistics graph
});
```

Any help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you consuming JSON to display "circle"?

Comment: You have a JSON object & u want it to be embedded in the HTML page? .. is that it?

Comment: @developerbh: Yeah, I have to use that json value key and trying to populate the circle statistics.